# Saving a macro usage log to SharePoint

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a novice with VBA (at best), but I'm trying to troubleshoot an issue creating a log when someone runs a Macro. I've shared the macro with others on the team, and would like to know if they're using it to gauge adoption. I've set up a SharePoint folder with read/write access for all, and up until today, the log was saving for me, but just me. I then upgraded to Office 2016 and it stopped working for me, too. Nobody who runs the macro receives any errors, just nothing is saved in the log. I'd love help troubleshooting what might be missing from the code below. There's likely a better way, but this worked on a previous team....

```
Sub log_output(sourcedoc, evaluation_document_path, debug_option)

  logpath = "https://share.xxxxx/log.xlsx"
  Dim logdoc As Excel.Workbook
  Set objExcel1 = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  
    On Error Resume Next
        Set logdoc = objExcel1.Workbooks.Open(FileName:=logpath, ReadOnly:=False)
                
    'check if the workbook exists
    If logdoc Is Nothing Then
      Exit Sub
    End If
    If (logdoc.ReadOnly) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
        
  
  'the file exists so report errors as normal
  On Error GoTo 0

  objExcel1.DisplayAlerts = False
      
  objExcel1.Visible = debug_option

  Set objsheet1 = objExcel1.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
   numrows = objsheet1.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
   objsheet1.range("A" & numrows + 1) = Now
   objsheet1.range("B" & numrows + 1) = (Environ$("Username"))
   objsheet1.range("C" & numrows + 1) = sourcedoc.FullName
   objsheet1.range("D" & numrows + 1) = evaluation_document_path
   
   
    logdoc.SaveAs logdoc.FullName, AccessMode:=xlExclusive, ConflictResolution:=True
    logdoc.Close (True)
    
    
    objExcel1.DisplayAlerts = True
  
    
End Sub
```